# change default emacs view command

Tags: emacs

The `C-c C-v` command in `emacs`. Sometimes it asks what viewer to use, and sometimes it just shows the document. If possible (within reasonable effort), I'd like it to never ask, just show.

Also, where is the default view tool command defined? I'd like to know how to set it, as I'd like to append options, so it (for example) will look like this `evince --fullscreen` (or just `-f`) instead of just `evince`.

The mode that I use is `LaTeX/P`.

(In response to a comment)

/etc/gnome/defaults.list:

```
application/pdf=evince.desktop
application/x-bzpdf=evince.desktop
application/x-gzpdf=evince.desktop
application/postscript=evince.desktop
application/x-bzpostscript=evince.desktop
application/x-gzpostscript=evince.desktop
image/x-eps=evince.desktop
image/x-bzeps=evince.desktop
image/x-gzeps=evince.desktop
application/x-dvi=evince.desktop
application/x-bzdvi=evince.desktop
application/x-gzdvi=evince.desktop
image/vnd.djvu=evince.desktop
image/tiff=evince.desktop
application/x-cbr=evince.desktop
application/x-cbz=evince.desktop
application/x-cb7=evince.desktop
```

Comment: What is your desktop environment?  Under Ubuntu 11.10, emacs (23.3.1) calls `xdg-open`, which you can set with the command `xdg-mime`.  As far as I remember, it is reading from a `defaults.list` file; you may have one in something like `~/.local/share/applications` or `/etc/gnome/defaults.list`. ... And, for what it's worth, `C-c C-v` never asks me about the viewer; have you changed your default view settings?

Comment: In `/etc/gnome/`, I found the file you mentioned (see post edit). There were some `evince` related stuff there, but nothing to do (?). Isn't this something you fix within `emacs`, or put in your `.emacs` file? (I have not configured `C-c C-v`.)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to find out simpler information but got sidetracked.  I wasn't sure what your set-up was (GNOME), or if you had fiddled with your (system-wide) .pdf viewer settings.  The first line you posted from `defaults.list` suggests that `emacs` shouldn't bother asking about which viewer to use..? Can you describe more explicitly when it does or doesn't ask?   As for the `--fullscreen` option, I've never worried about that before.  (I'll take a look, but others might be much quicker.)

Comment: There is, for starters: `M-x customize-variable RET TeX-view-program-selection`.

Comment: You can also customize `TeX-output-view-style`, but I can't get it to accept the `-f` option for some reason.

Comment: I can’t explain the code, but here are two lines from my .emacs which you can try, substituting “evince” where I have “mupdf.”  Sorry, I can’t tell you about fullscreen — one thing I like about mupdf is that it takes up so little screen real estate.

Line 1: '(TeX-output-view-style (quote (("^dvi$" "." "evince %o") ("^ps$" "." "evince %o") ("^pdf$" "." "mupdf %o") ("^html?$" "." "firefox %o"))))
Line 2: '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote (((output-dvi style-pstricks) "Evince") (output-dvi "Evince") (output-pdf "xdg-open") (output-html "xdg-open"))))

Comment: @Thérèse -- this looks like you used `customize-variable`.  But what is your default viewer?  (Try opening a .pdf with `xdg-open` to test.)  Incidentally, I too like `mupdf` for regular viewing; you may also find [zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura/) to your liking.  It has better support for bookmarks.

Comment: @jon — Yes, I used customize-variable; unfortunately, it’s not very friendly in the case of these two items, and I tried many times before stumbling upon a formula that worked.  My xdg-open for pdf is mupdf (I don’t know why I need both TeX-output-view-style and TeX-view-program-selection…), and you’re right that zathura is very useful.

Answer (score 5):

First things first, if you don't know what you are doing, use the `M-x customize-variable` to modify `TeX-output-view-style` and `TeX-view-program-selection`; from these menus, you should be able to declare that you want to use `evince --fullscreen` for the first variable, and `Evince` for the second.  If you do this, you should end up with the following in your `.emacs` (cut down to the relevant portions):

```
(custom-set-variables
;; default warning comments from the customize-variable command
  '(TeX-output-view-style (quote (("^pdf$" "." "evince --fullscreen %o") ...<other options will be declared>...
   )
  '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ( ...< various options >... (output-pdf "Evince") ...)))
```

Note: do **not** cut and paste any of the above.  I'm just showing you the parts that should be of interest to you.

With these settings, now `C-c C-v` and `C-c C-c` (once AUCTeX thinks it's the appropriate action) will use `Evince` with the `--fullscreen` option.

Comment: `TeX-output-view-style` seems to have no effect. I can put whatever there and it does not change the behavior. `TeX-view-program-selection` on the other hand, if I put something nonsensical there, it breaks the viewing altogether.

Comment: @EmanuelBerg -- did you use both at the same time?  I took all this stuff, because I don't want to call Evince with `--fullscreen`, but when I made the changes, `TeX-ouput-view-style` listed several instances for pdf. I made all of them follow the pattern shown above; but do not try to give options to `TeX-view-program-selection`.  Perhaps you could edit your question to show what you get in `.emacs` after using `M-x customize-variable`.  (You can get rid of the `defaults.list` stuff, but it might be worth mentioning the OS/etc. for future readers of the question.)

Comment: It looks like this: `(custom-set-variables
 '(TeX-output-view-style (quote (("^pdf$" "." "evince --fullscreen %o"))))
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Evince")))) ; and then some unrelated things.` `TeX-output-view-style` does not seem to affect anything with or without `TeX-view-program-selection`. But `TeX-view-program-selection` works as we expect it to, replacing `Evince` with `xpdf` and you get a `xpdf` window instead.

Comment: Really?  You made the change with `M-x customize-variable`, and it only made an addition for pdf?  When I went through the process, it gave me settings for .pdf, .dvi, .html, etc.; in some cases 'double' settings (for reasons I don't know).

Comment: Yes. I have GNU Emacs 23.4.1 and did exactly as you in LaTeX/P mode. Anyway, I'll start reading the documentation more closely and get back to you if I solve this. It seems such an easy fix it is too annoying to fail.